# .How do I prove an implication of disjunction?

Tags: logic

I want to prove that
 A ⇒  B           (1).

I write the implication 
 A ⇒ (B ∨ C)      (2).

I can prove  by contradiction that (2) is true, then I prove that C is false.

Is this means that the implication 
    A ⇒ B is true?

Answer (score 0):

If $C \equiv 0$, then $B \lor C \equiv B \lor 0 \equiv$ B, so that $(A \implies B) \equiv (A \implies (B \lor C ))$. So if $(A \implies (B \lor C ))$ takes value $1$, so does $(A \implies B)$, and conversely for $0$.

Comment: I have proved that C is false after proving that (1) is true by contradiction. In the proof of (1), I have used (not C).

Comment: When C is false both your (1) and (2) are logically equivalent. That means they will take the same truth values, so if you proved that one is true, so should the other be, do you agree ?

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking whether $A\to B$ is a valid inference from $A\to(B\vee C)$ and $\neg C$?   It is.

Take $\neg C$ and $A\to(B\vee C)$ as premises.   By assuming $A$, you may derive that $B$ or $C$ will be true, but $C$ is promised to be false, leaving only that $B$ may be true.   Therefore $A\to B$ is entailed by the premises.

So if you have proven $A\to (B\vee C)$ and have proven $\neg C$, then you may infer that $A\to B$ is provable.

Comment: I agree with the two responses. 
When we can't prove directly (1),
The proof of (2) is an indirect proof of (1), if C is false.